# CakePHP 2.2.3 FormHelper cannot set default meridian when using minute interval and default minute value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2, formhelper

In my application, the following is expected to output the hour, minute, and meridian `<select>`s for a 12-hour time with 4:30pm selected by default:

```
echo $this->Form->input('time_example', array(
    'interval' => 5,
    'timeFormat' => '12',
    'type' => 'time',
    'selected' => array(
        'hour' => '4',
        'min' => '30',
        'meridian' => 'pm'
    )
));
```

But the default selected time is actually displayed as 4:30am.

After some fiddling, I found that it will correctly default to 4:30pm if `interval` is removed from the options, and it will correctly default to 4:00pm if `min` is removed from the options.

I dug into FormHelper.php and found this in FormHelper::dateTime(), starting at line 2246 (in CakePHP version 2.2.3):

```
if (!empty($interval) && $interval > 1 && !empty($min)) {
    $current = new DateTime();
    if ($year !== null) {
        $current->setDate($year, $month, $day);
    }
    if ($hour !== null) {
        $current->setTime($hour, $min);
    }
    $change = (round($min * (1 / $interval)) * $interval) - $min;
    $current->modify($change > 0 ? "+$change minutes" : "$change minutes");
    $newTime = explode(' ', $current->format('Y m d H i a'));
    list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $meridian) = $newTime;
}
```

This appears that if both `$interval` and `$min` are set, this prevents `$min` from conflicting with `$interval`, but `$meridian` gets overwritten with [the assumption](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) that `$hour` is in a 24-hour format. This forces `$meridian` to become 'am' for any value of `$hour` less than 12, making a default selection of 4:30pm impossible.

Am I using the helper incorrectly, or is this an error in the core?

Comment: I have also confirmed that the quoted block of code from FormHelper is in the latest stable release (2.3.1), where it begins on line 2376.

Comment: If this is a valid issue please submit a ticket for it - ideally with a patch to fix it. This can be done via github pull request.

Comment: Is it solved with https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/f1d192f282486273d68c7334a18ebbd6f724cfce ?

Comment: No, that commit doesn't affect the quoted block of code in FormHelper. $meridian is still being overwritten with an assumption of a 24-hour format. Since this seems to be a genuine error in the core, I'll see if I can whip up a pull request. If it's accepted, I'll close this question.

Comment: Pull request submitted: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/1182

Comment: Sidenote: I would not set default values via "selected", but properly via controller and $this->request->data. I wonder if that would make a difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been corrected in [this merge](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/b8215050148565b7d8b412021403c8519ac71437).